# How to create a view of unread comments on own nodes for the user's profile page?

Tags: 7, views, rules, comments, flags

I'd like to create a view for the user's profile page that displays all unread comments on the nodes he/she created. When I say 'unread', I mean that the page where the comment is situated (namely, the node's page) hasn't been visited by the user yet. In other words: when the user hasn't read a new comment, it will be displayed in the view; once the user has read it, it will disappear in the view.

I've already set up a view that simply displays all comments on the user's nodes, but I can't find an extra 'Filter criteria' or 'Relationship' that filters out the unread ones.

Can you help me?

---

**Edit:** I created a flag called 'Read' ('Reactie gelezen' in Dutch) with the [Flag](http://drupal.org/project/flag) module and a rule 'Comment read' that automatically flags comments with 'Read' when they're viewed. I've also granted every user the permission to flag comments with the 'Read' flag (although they won't see the flag links above their comment of course).

My rule works perfectly and the flagging works manually too. The view however, doesn't work properly. These are my settings:

[image: Settings view]

Both uid's were provided the default value 'User ID from URL'.

What did I do wrong?

Comment: This may sound stupid, but what is your criteria for a comment being unread?  What will trigger a comment as being marked as read?

Comment: When I say 'unread', I mean that the page where the comment is situated (namely, the node's page) hasn't been visited by the user yet.

Comment: Hi, What is the view output ?
And how the "flag" works in this scenario, as well.. ? 
Is it ajax-jquery or ?

Comment: Also, can you try displaying all the unread comments, without the user filter....

Comment: @OlegVidenov: I discribed the view's output on my question: it contains all the unread comments on the user's nodes. I added a link to my exported 'Read' flag. User don't see this flag, it's just a workaround for the view. I really have the intention to show the unread comments *with* the user filter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Flag module only keeps rows in the database for content where a flag is set. I.e. when something is **not** flagged, there will be no corresponding row in the database.

The problem is, that views will generate a query which looks something like this (for a user with `uid=12` and a flag with `fid=1`):

```
SELECT cid FROM comment AS c
INNER JOIN node AS n ON c.nid = n.nid
LEFT JOIN flagging AS f ON c.cid = f.entity_id AND f.fid = '1'
WHERE n.uid = '12' AND f.uid = '12'
```

However in order to select all comments for a given user excluding those which are **not** flagged, you need an SQL subquery:

```
SELECT cid FROM comment AS c
INNER JOIN node AS n ON c.nid = n.nid
WHERE n.uid = '12' AND c.cid NOT IN (
    SELECT f.entity_id FROM flagging AS f
    WHERE f.fid = '1' AND f.uid = '12'
)
```

AFAIK Views has no built-in support for subqueries. I therefore recommend you to reverse the logic and implement the following:

- Add a comment-flag `is_new`
- Whenever a new comment is posted, execute a rule which sets this flag on behalf of the content author.
- Whenever a node is viewed by its author, execute a rule which removes all `is_new`-flags on the associated comments (this is essentially the same rule you already have, except that you need to reverse the flagging-logic).
- Configure the view just as you did before but remove the `flagged=false` filter, instead configure the flag-relationship such that only flagged content is included.