# How can I make a view that shows users all the who have flagged a single user?

Tags: views, users, rules, flags

**Background**

I want to add a tab to the user profile that shows the logged in user which other users have viewed his/her profile.  I want to control this list in Views.

Until recently, I have been using the [User Visits](https://drupal.org/project/user_visits) module.  However, this module does not integrate with Views and is no longer actively maintained.

I started building this using Views, Rules, and Flag.  Specifically, I created a flag **Viewed profile**, and then made a Rule to automatically flag a profile when a user visits another user's profile.

I then created a view of users with two displays.

**My View**

The first display, *Profiles I visited*, has a relationship to the **Viewed profile** flag and simply lists all profiles flagged (visited) by the current user.  Easy.

Now I want to create a second display, *Users who have visited me*.  In this case, I want to display all the users who have flagged the  current user.  However, I can't figure out how to do this.

I can add a relationship, *Flags (by any user)*, but there could quickly be 10,000+ such flags on my site, so I am worried about the performance implications of loading all the flags like that.  Also, even if I load all the flags, I don't see how to easily filter them to users who have flagged the current user.

Instead, it seems like it would be easier to create a second flag, **User who viewed me**, and attach both flags (**Viewed profile** and **User who viewed me**) with a rule at the same time when a user visits a profile.  However, this seems like unnecessary duplication of information to me, since both flags link the same two users at the same time.  Is there a more elegant way to display this data in Views that will not lead to performance issues down the line?

Comment: I have a similar question about viewed comments: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/88529/how-to-create-a-view-of-unread-comments-on-own-nodes-for-the-users-profile-page. I think both solutions will be quite alike.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Add a relationship, **Flags: User's flaggings** for your flag.  Uncheck *Include only users who have flagged content.*
2. Add a contextual filter, **Flags: Content ID** and set *Provide default value* to *User ID from logged in user*.

This was not intuitive, but it appears to do the trick.