# How to display only New comments from all nodes of a content type?

Tags: 7, views, comments

**In short:**

Is there any way to display list of **New/Unread** comments from all nodes of a content type for the logged in user?

**In Detail:**

I've created a "content" view of "basic" type to display new/unread comments for the logged in user.

But I found the way only to display the count for "new comments".

*View Details:*

**Relationship:** Content:Author

**Filter Criteria:** (author) User: Current (Yes) > (It display the nodes created by currently logged in users)

[image]

*Fields:*

**Content:** Title (Title)

**Content:** New comments (New Comments)

**Output:**

[image]

Is there any way to display only list of unread/new comments for all nodes of a content type for the logged in user?

Comment: How about you try starting with **created a "comments" view** instead of **created a "content" view**? Other approach: any other "relationship" available that may help? Haven't tried it (yet) myself though.

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens I jsut see your comment. Yeah Infact I tried that way too. but the `Filter Criteria: (author) User: Current (Yes)` is considering the comment author instead of node author I guess. Trying hard to achieve this

Comment: Where are you displaying the View? If you can somehow load the correct uid (e.g. if you display the View on the user pages, the uid is in the URL), I suppose my old question http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/88529/how-to-create-a-view-of-unread-comments-on-own-nodes-for-the-users-profile-page should answer yours. Also, mpdonadio's comment applies here: "What is your criteria for a comment being unread? What will trigger a comment as being marked as read?"